# How to Add Collection Best selling Related Products to Shopify Cart Page

Tags: shopify

I want to show collection related products best selling on  shopify cart page. I tried some product loop but doesn't work.

This is my code which i added:

```
<div class="row products">
  {% if collection.best-selling.products.size > 0 %} 
  {% for product in collection.best-selling.products %}
  <li>
    <img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape  }}" />
    <a class="shop-now" href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.title | escape  }}</a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %} 
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Anybody got any idea how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in yout code.

#### Liquid error

When targeting a specific collection you must use the `collections` keyword, not `collection` ( `collection` is  available only on the collection page and returns that collection). So you should use here `collections.best-selling`.

This is deprecated `product_img_url: 'medium'` don't used named size such as `small/medium/large etc...`, use numbered sizes like `600x600` (where this is `WIDTHxHEIGHT` without cropping or changing the aspect ratio of the image).

#### HTML validation error

Outputting a `li` without it being in `ul` or `ol` is invalid HTML code and this will make your HTML code validation fail.

#### Your code should look like this

This assumes that you have a collection with a handle `best-selling`.

```
<div class="row products">
  {% if collections.best-selling.products.size > 0 %} 
    <ul>
      {% for product in collections.best-selling.products %}
        <li>
          <img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: '600x' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape  }}" />
          <a class="shop-now" href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.title | escape  }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %} 
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```